# FriendlyPix secruity write rule not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have used the FriendlyPix database as a base for my database.

I have tried to apply the following security rule to:

1. Only allow authenticated user to insert new post
2. Edit or delete existing post can only be performed by post creator

I have used the security rule from the [FriendlyPix GitHub repository](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web/blob/master/database-rules.json), however when I run the simulator I always get "Write Denied" error message.

I have tried various versions of the write rule, but all fail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write to `/posts`. In JavaScript code your simulation is similar to:

```
var postsRef = firebase.database().ref("posts");
postref.set( { "-Kj...": { author: { full_name: "Stuart", uid: "..." }}});
```

Since no-one has write permission on that level, the write is rejected.

It is possible to accomplish what you need, but you'll need to make sure you only write to `/posts/-Kj....`. In JavaScript code that would be something like:

```
var postsRef = firebase.database().ref("posts");
postref.push().set({ author: { full_name: "Stuart", uid: "..." }});
```

Now you're writing to a specific post, which is allowed by your security rules.

Comment: Thank you Frank, does this basically mean it's not possible to test this security rule using the simulator?

Comment: It's quite possible to test this rule. You just have to write to a lower level, just like the code does. If you simulate writing to `/posts/-Kj...`, the simulator will show that it's allowed.

Comment: Btw: your write operation would succeed if you use `update()`, since it only updates a `/posts/-Kj...` child. But the simulator only simulates `set()` operations, which correctly fails.